# Initialize new object and set values with Java 8

Tags: java, java-8

Right now I am passing `to` the following way, by creating the object first, calling the methods to set the values, then passing it to another object method.

```
To to = new To();
to.setEmail("emailaddress@gmail.com");
to.setName("John Smith");

Headers headers = new Headers();
headers.setTo(Arrays.asList(to));
```

Is it possible to do everything I am doing above related to the `to` object while calling `headers.setTo`?

```
Headers headers = new Headers();
headers.setTo(Is it possible to Initialize and set the "To" values in here?);
```

Comment: Make `To` immutable (optional, but recommended) and provide a constructor that accepts both email and name.

Comment: If you want to chain your methods -  have them return the object they are called on.

Comment: I am not too familiar with Lambda expressions. But is this something that I might be able to do with Lambda expressions?

Comment: @Arya No, lambda will not help here.

Comment: As a side note, the preferred way to create a single element list is `Collections.singletonList(obj)` rather than `Arrays.asList(obj)`.

Answer (score 2):

Not with the POJO approach. Either you create a constructor in To having all fields you need as parameters or go for the builder pattern.

Comment: _"Not with the POJO approach"_ Are you saying that your solutions do not create an object?

Comment: Ok, so the term "POJO" may be a little bit confusing here. My bad. We used the term "POJO" for several years for Java Beans having some attributes, a default constructor and getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible only if there is a constructor in the class To that takes the mentioned arguments like this:

```
public class To {

    private String Email;
    private String Name;

    // The constructor
    public To(String Email, String Name) {
        this.Email = Email;
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    // ... more code ...
}
```

Then your call could look like:

```
Headers headers = new Headers();
headers.setTo(Arrays.asList(new To("emailaddress@gmail.com","John Smith")));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using [com.sun.net.httpserver.Headers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/Headers.html). If you are having your own customized `Headers` class and `To` class, you can try the below modification.

```
class Headers{
    //....Other variables, getters & setters
    List<? extends To> to = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setTo(Supplier<List> toSupplier){
        toSupplier.get().foreach(to::add);
    }
}
```

//Add a new constructor to `To` class which accept the *name & email*. Then you can re-write it as follows:

```
Headers headers = new Headers();
Supplier<List> toSupplier = () -> Arrays.asList(new To("John Smith","emailaddress@gmail.com"));
headers.setTo(toSupplier);
```

OR

```
Headers headers = new Headers();
headers.setTo(() -> Arrays.asList(new To("John Smith","emailaddress@gmail.com")));
```

Comment: How does your supplier make anything easier?

Comment: Besides the fact that you are using *raw types*, misspelled method names and a discouraged coding style (adding to a list using `forEach` instead of collecting) and a misleading method name, as `setTo` actually does an inefficient equivalent of `addAll`, I have to ask the same as @zeroflagL, what problem is providing the list via `Supplier` and the additional copy operation supposed to solve?

Comment: I was basically trying to write it with the use of a lambda expression. *(Sorry about the typos, I didn't use any IDE, I just typed the whole thing in a text editor)*

Answer (score 0):

Unless you can add a constructor with input parameters for the `To` class the only option (and a good one) is the factory/builder pattern.

Define this:

```
public class ToBuilder {
    public static To createTo(String email, String name) {
        To to = new To();
        to.setEmail(email);
        to.setName(name);
        return to;
    }
}
```

and then you can do:

```
Headers headers = new Headers();
headers.setTo(ToBuilder.createTo("emailaddress@gmail.com","John Smith"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since [java-16](/questions/tagged/java-16), you can use `To` as a `record` which will make it immutable by default too

```java
public record To(String email, String name) {

}

Headers headers = new Headers();
headers.setTo(new To("emailaddress@gmail.com", "John Smith"));
```

Answer (score 0):

As much I can understand, you are looking for Lambda to create a list of the object.
As Arrays.asList is allowing Object (public static  List asList(T... a)), we can not pass a function to that.

I can see one workaround by writing a new method and pass Supplier to that. This way you can write your own Supplier while using that method.

i.e:

```
List<To> tos = createList(()->{
  To to = new To();
  to.setEmail("emailaddress@gmail.com");
  to.setName("John Smith");
  return to;
},()->{
  To to = new To();
  to.setEmail("emailaddress@gmail.com");
  to.setName("John Smith");
  return to;
});


private <T> List<T> createList(Supplier<T>... suppliers)
{
    return Arrays.stream(suppliers).map(supplier -> {
        return supplier.get();
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```